# Circular Reveal shows black background

Tags: android, animation, fade, clip, circularreveal

I'm trying to implement animation [shown here](https://material.uplabs.com/posts/compact-login). It works fine except for unreveal animation, which shows black screen for a moment. The glitch exists not on all devices/api versions. Genymotion emulator of Google Nexus 10 (API 22) does show the glitch.

[image]

Unreveal use complex set of animations:

- fade
- layout moving
- CircularReveal with end radius less than start radius
- e.t.c.

I tried to set `background`/`foreground`/`tint` of layouts to `@null`/`@android:color/transparent` and e.t.c., but it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glitch occurs only with 3 things at once in code:

- `CircularReveal` layout with items
- Fade layout of `CircularReveal` or its child layout
- set `clipChildren=false` on revealing layout

I needed to use `clipChildren` to make effect of moving `CircularReveal` circle with stable content which do not move, except for close-button.

As I can guess, the problem was with clipping. `CircularReveal` use clipping, `clipChildren` use it too, and then `alpha` made it dirty (black). I can't comprehend why it is happening in Android SDK, but I have a solution:

disable `clipChildren` (set it `true`) when you don't need it. I did it on unreveal animation. Result is below:

[image]

P.S.
If you have more specific answer with details on the cause of the glitch, I would gladly mark your answer as correct one.

P.P.S.
For anyone, who interested in animation implementation, I [shared it here](https://github.com/Nexen23/CompactLogin/tree/master).